# How to increase spinner window size in VF Page?

Tags: visualforce, lightning, css

```
        <apex:actionstatus id="sts">
         <apex:facet name="start">
          <div class="slds-spinner_container">
             <div id="mySpinner" role="status" class="slds-spinner slds- 
                 spinner_medium slds-spinner_brand">
            <span class="slds-assistive-text">Loading..</span>
            <div class="slds-spinner__dot-a"></div>
            <div class="slds-spinner__dot-b"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </apex:facet>
     </apex:actionstatus>  

    <apex:commandButton value="Add" rerender="errorMessages"
                oncomplete="tSaveAndContinueButton('enable')"
                action="{!addSegment}" 
                styleclass="slds-button slds-button_neutral" status="sts"/>
```

[image]

The spinner is not covering the whole page. When I scroll the page User can able to edit the fields in vf page. We should not allow users to enter any data while spinner is loading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We usually face this issue when we make `showHeader=false` on `visualforce` page. With header not present, some of the css files does not get loaded, hence we see this differences.

With `showHeader= true`, everything should work fine without even setting the style attribute of the container.

So the solution for your problem i.e. when you want to show spinner in entire visualforce page without the header, you will have to add style `position:fixed` to the container div i.e. to the div with class `slds-spinner_container`, so that it covers the entire visualforce page.

Here is the code that should work for you

```
<apex:actionstatus id="sts">
     <apex:facet name="start">
      <div class="slds-spinner_container" style="position:fixed">
         <div id="mySpinner" role="status" class="slds-spinner slds-spinner_medium slds-spinner_brand">
        <span class="slds-assistive-text">Loading..</span>
        <div class="slds-spinner__dot-a"></div>
        <div class="slds-spinner__dot-b"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </apex:facet>
</apex:actionstatus>
```

Comment: Hi Vijay, It is not working even I add style="position:relative"

Comment: Hi @chris, I have updated the answer, this should work for you.